# Trace and determinant of characteristic polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra

I Just started learning linear algebra. In my homework exercise i have this question:
The characteristic polynomial of a square matrix $A$ of order $3$ is $|\lambda I-A|=\lambda^{3}+3\lambda^{2}+4\lambda-3$
Let $x=$ Trace$(A)$ and $y=|A|$, Then ,

(A) $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{3}{4}$

(B) $\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{4}{3}$

(C) $x=y=-3$

(D) $x=3$ and $y=-3$

I usually find sum and product of roots using characteristic polynomial. 
. My trace when i calculated is $-3$ (sum of roots) and $|A|=3$(product of roots)
But it doesnt matches with options. Can someone tell me where did i do wrong ?

Comment: How can $x/y$ be equal to two different numbers?

Comment: The linear term of characteristic polynomial of a $3 \times 3$ matrix is not always $1$ as indicated. It is $\lambda_2 \lambda_3 + \lambda_3 \lambda_1 + \lambda_1 \lambda_2 =  \frac{1}{2} [(\operatorname{trace} A)^2 - \operatorname{trace}(A)^2)]$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown   You mean in options ?

Comment: @Travis yes sir. Let me edit that out.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CharacteristicPolynomial.html. Option D is correct.

Comment: What's A?  There's a mistake somewhere...

Comment: You are correct: the trace is $-3$ and the determinant is $3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown What about the answer PRC gave below.

Comment: @ChrisCuster their might be but i just copied my question i rechecked it and it looks same.

Comment: @mate89 http://prntscr.com/i49zy2 I followed this didnt I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a misconception of sign i.e.  $(-1)^3\{\lambda^{3}-(Trace(A))\lambda^{2}+\lambda-|A|\}$ = $|\lambda I - A| $. So your last option is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that's how it works? Could you provide me any source for it please.

Comment: It depends on how the polynomial is defined (it varies from author to author) some use $\det(A-\lambda I)$ and some $\det(\lambda I - A)$. As a rule of thumb, substitute $0$ into the polynomial and see what you get: in the case above $\det(\lambda I - A)$, it becomes $\det((0) I - A)=\det( - A)$ and for $\det(A-\lambda I)$, it becomes $\det(A-(0) I)=\det(A)$. Then set your sign convention accordingly.